# Check verification of age

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup

I have some code, but its not working for me. I think the cookie doesnt work good, because every moment when I try get to the site, the popup shows. Please help. Thanks.

```
  if ($.cookie("userAge") == null) {
    displayVerification();
  }

  $("#verify").click(function() {
    $( "#verification-dialog" ).dialog("close");
    $.cookie("userAge", userAge);
    });   

  $("#no-verify").click(function() {
    window.location='http://google.pl';
    });  

  function displayVerification() {    
    $( "#verification-dialog" ).dialog({      
      closeOnEscape: false,
      dialogClass: "no-close",  
      draggable: false,
      minWidth: 490,
      modal: true,  
      resizable: false,     
      title: "Weryfikacja wieku"
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'll bet you `$.cookie("userAge")` does'nt return `null`, try console.logging it and see what it returns, I would guess `undefined` or just an empty string, probably `undefined`, as the variable `userAge` looks like it's `undefined` ?

Comment: $.cookie("userAge", userAge); where is affected userAge ? also maybe close after the cookie, not before

Comment: Do you have a server set up? Cookies don't work if you access the page using `file://`.

Answer (score -1):

Cookies have problem working in `localhost`. You better host your site to web check it out. And try `($.cookie('userAge') == undefined)` instead of `($.cookie('userAge') == null)`

Edited: I gave as `($.cookie("userAge") == undefined)` before. Now changed it to single quoted. Sorry about the typo

Comment: I have a server set up. I changed to undefined instead of null, and I have the same problem.

Comment: Create `else` to forward to the next page then. Meanwhile I try figure out the problem. Did you try printing the value of cookie? What did it return?

Comment: Hold on, try using `' '` instead of `" "`. Like `($.cookie('userAge') == undefined)`

Comment: There is no difference between single and double quotes in JavaScript.

Comment: I understand, but isn't it worth trying.

Comment: No, because there's zero chance that it makes any difference.